# spring security encode password with bcrypt algorithm

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

i get something strange... in spring security for encode password..

i am trying to change my password and save it to database..but i always get error because defferent string..

like this..

in controller ..

```
println "password  = "+oldPass
println "password 1 = "+springSecurityService.encodePassword('password')
println "password 2 = "+springSecurityService.encodePassword('password')
println "password  = "+springSecurityService.encodePassword(oldPass)
```

and this ooutput

[image]

its strange...everytime i encodePassword, i will get different result.

i am using grails 3.0.5 and use bcrypt algorithm

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
```

i put this line in application.groovy

like this

```
    // Added by the Spring Security Core plugin:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.akiong.security.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.akiong.security.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.akiong.security.Role'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'com.akiong.security.RequestMap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                ['permitAll'],
    '/error':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index':           ['permitAll'],
    '/index.gsp':       ['permitAll'],
    '/shutdown':        ['permitAll'],
    '/assets/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/js/**':        ['permitAll'],
    '/**/css/**':       ['permitAll'],
    '/**/images/**':    ['permitAll'],
    '/**/favicon.ico':  ['permitAll']
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
```

but when i create an user account with bootstrap and save it to database..
then i login ...it run with correctly..

[image]

[image]

Comment: btw, it's much easier for other people if you put code samples, output, etc in plain text instead of images. so it can be cited, or used for an experiment before answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It's a feature*. `bcrypt` uses a random salt, so each time it generates a different hash even for same password.

If you want to check if entered password is valid, you need to use `passwordEncoder.isPasswordvalid` for Grails, like:

```
assert passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid( 
       '$2a$10$Qb7ENpWOSsFUS2UvwT1BRefZhn55roXPgUI8fjJRm6c/nR3JIQP8a',
       'password', null)
assert passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(
       '$2a$10$sC3.yrmNn2VLS2Aer359rei/DxoLlwFq7s6ndAHm10ncyQpIr3MfO',
       'password', null)
```

or for plain Spring Security `passwordEncoder.matches`:

```
assert passwordEncoder.matches('password', 
       '$2a$10$Qb7ENpWOSsFUS2UvwT1BRefZhn55roXPgUI8fjJRm6c/nR3JIQP8a')
assert passwordEncoder.matches('password', 
       '$2a$10$sC3.yrmNn2VLS2Aer359rei/DxoLlwFq7s6ndAHm10ncyQpIr3MfO')
```

To autowire `passwordEncoder` bean just define it as a property of your class:

```
def passwordEncoder
```

Comment: println "password 1 = "+passwordEncoder.matches('password','$2a$10$JNUJ3pRiwnOMkVYPRpbdeujyuBLTavozVLinHRnf5MK8VHkif2IGG')... i cannot use passwordEncoder

Comment: did you wire it into your service/controller/etc? it's a bean provided by spring

Comment: how? i dont know..i just add this grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt' to application.groovy

Comment: oh did you mean call def springSecurityService? i wire it...thats why i can use springSecurityService.encodePassword

Comment: no, I mean `passwordEncoder`, not `springSecurityService`. Also, actually I think Grails have different implementation, so method could be called `.isPasswordValid(hashed, 'password')`. See answer update

Comment: see my update post..i get an error like that... i already add def passwordEncoder after def cityService

Comment: when i try this assert `passwordEncoder.matches('password','$2a$10$JNUJ3pRiwnOMkVYPRpbdeujyuBLTavozVLinHRnf5MK8VHkif2IGG')`.. i get this error `No signature of method: grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.encoding.BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches()`

Comment: yes, try `isPasswordValid(hashed, 'password', null)`

Comment: can i know `isPasswordValid(<this is encrypted string>, <this is real string>,<what is this?>)`?

Comment: `isPasswordValid(hashed, plainpassword, salt)`. you can't use salt for bcrypt, so it must be `null`

Comment: If bcrypt uses a random salt each time, how can it ever find out if the user entered the correct password? it would hash to something different everytime...I don't understand.

Comment: @Aerovistae just get this salt from he hash, it's first 128bit/22chars from the hash. Or better use provided `passwordEncoder.matches`